# SQL to limit output to certain months and years

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that only displays employees hired from certain months like April and May as well as exclude employees hired in certain years, but I'm having trouble finding any resources online that explain how to do this. I'm using Oracle SQL so the YEAR and MONTH commands I have used are met with invalid identifier. This is what I have so far.

```
 SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, 
        SUBSTR(LAST_NAME || ' ' || FIRST_NAME, 1, 25) AS "Full Name", 
        JOB_ID,
        TO_CHAR(last_day(hire_date), 'Month fmDd"st" "of" YYYY') AS "Start Date"
 FROM EMPLOYEES
 WHERE HIRE_DATE NOT IN ('01-01-1992' TO_DATE('12-31-1992'));
```

Comment: any sample data?

Comment: Something like this?:
`SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, 
        SUBSTR(LAST_NAME || ' ' || FIRST_NAME, 1, 25) AS "Full Name", 
        JOB_ID,
        TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Month fmDd"st" "of" YYYY') AS "Start Date"
 FROM EMPLOYEES
 WHERE HIRE_DATE NOT IN ('01-01-1992' TO_DATE('12-31-1992'))
 AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(hire_date,'mm')) in (4,5);`

Comment: Is sample data necessary for this? I'm just trying to understand how you would exclude certain years or months for a search, similarly to how you would only want to search for an employee with a certain job title.

Comment: you need where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps?

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, SUBSTR(LAST_NAME || ' ' || FIRST_NAME, 1, 25) AS "Full Name",
JOB_ID,
TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Month fmDd"th" "of" YYYY') AS "Start Date"
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE HIRE_DATE NOT 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-1992','MM-DD-YYYY') 
    AND TO_DATE('12-31-1992','MM-DD-YYYY') 
AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(hire_date,'mm')) in (4,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `EXTRACT` for such conditions .

```
SELECT employee_id,
       "full name",
       "start date"
FROM   (SELECT employee_id,
               Substr(last_name
                      || ' '
                      || first_name, 1, 25) AS
               "Full Name",
               job_id,
               To_char(Last_day(hire_date), 'Month fmDd"st" "of" YYYY') AS
               "Start Date"
                      ,
               Extract (year FROM hire_date)
                      hired_year,
               Extract (month FROM hire_date)
               hired_month
        FROM   hr.employees)
WHERE  hired_year NOT IN ( 1992, 1993 )
       AND hired_month NOT IN ( 4, 5 );
```